# Custom adapter for listview not working

Tags: android, json, android-layout, listview

I'm having trouble creating an adapter to my list filled with an array json I get from my web service query.

**EDIT**

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

Context context;
private ArrayList<RowItem> originalList;
private ArrayList<RowItem> items;
private CountryFilter filter;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    this.items.addAll(items);
    this.originalList = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    this.originalList.addAll(items);
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtNombre;
    TextView txtTicket;
    TextView txtAsiento;
    TextView txtNumero;
    TableLayout tblLayout;
    TableRow row;

}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
 if (filter == null){
  filter  = new CountryFilter();
 }
 return filter;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public RowItem getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lista, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.row = (TableRow)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
        holder.txtNombre = (TextView)holder.row.getChildAt(0);
        holder.txtTicket = (TextView)holder.row.getChildAt(1);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtNombre.setText(rowItem.getNombre());
    //holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
    holder.txtTicket.setText(rowItem.getTicket());

    return convertView;
}

private class CountryFilter extends Filter
{

 @Override
 protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

  constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
  FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
  if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
  {
  ArrayList<RowItem> filteredItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

  for(int i = 0, l = originalList.size(); i < l; i++)
  {
   RowItem asistente = originalList.get(i);
   if(asistente.toString().replace('á', 'a').toLowerCase().contains(constraint) || asistente.toString().replace('é', 'e').toLowerCase().contains(constraint) || asistente.toString().replace('í', 'i').toLowerCase().contains(constraint) || asistente.toString().replace('ó', 'o').toLowerCase().contains(constraint) || asistente.toString().replace('ú', 'u').toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
        filteredItems.add(asistente);
  }
  result.count = filteredItems.size();
  result.values = filteredItems;
  }
  else
  {
   synchronized(this)
   {
    result.values = originalList;
    result.count = originalList.size();
   }
  }
  return result;
 }

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 @Override
 protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
     items = (ArrayList<RowItem>)results.values;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
      clear();
      for(int i = 0, l = items.size(); i < l; i++){
          System.out.println("RESULTADO:"+items.get(i));
          add(items.get(i));
          notifyDataSetInvalidated();
      }
    }
   }
 }
```

My problem is in the getView function. When charged my gives me the error:

```
08-06 11:48:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(10018): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 11:48:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(10018): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.google.zxing.client.android.R$id.tabla_cuerpo
08-06 11:48:42.505: E/AndroidRuntime(10018):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.CustomListViewAdapter.getView(CustomListViewAdapter.java:70)
```

my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tabla_cuerpo" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:gravity="center_horizontal"  android:id="@+id/textView0" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:text="Validaciones"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView  android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/txtNombre" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="Celda1"/>
        <TextView  android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/txtTicket" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="Celda2"/>
        <TextView  android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/txtAsiento" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="Celda3"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

The problem arises when I loaded the view and can not upload data. The strange thing is that I use the same code in another project with the same format as JSON and working properly. I have seen several custom code in the getView event adapter and exactly to mine but I think my mistake are in my elements and can not find how to fix it.

Comment: The error you are getting is related to not being able to find the View with the ID `tabla_cuerpo` in layout  `R.id.tabla_cuerpo`. You sure those are the right files?

Comment: @Andy Clearly there is error, but yes. Sure those are the files.

Comment: please recheck the file name if it is lista. maybe its not and you have another file lista. or maybe you have to layouts with the name lista for different devices and the ones loaded tabla_cuerpo id not set for it.

Comment: Verify that way, change the file name but still the same thing happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please override the getCount and getItemId as well.

updating answer with code:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return itemList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

and please don't use getChildAt(VIEW ID) , you have to use findViewByID

```
      holder.txtNombre = (TextView)holder.row.getChildAt(R.id.txtNombre);
      holder.txtTicket = (TextView)holder.row.getChildAt(R.id.txtTicket);
```

**Thx for the hint to @PPartisan**

By the way, you can do the same with less IDs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <TextView android:gravity="center_horizontal"  android:id="@+id/textView0" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:text="Validaciones"/>

</TableRow>
<TableRow  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView  android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/txtNombre" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="Celda1"/>

    <TextView  android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/txtTicket" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="Celda2"/>

    <TextView  android:layout_margin="1dip" android:id="@+id/txtAsiento" android:layout_weight="0.3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="Celda3"/>

</TableRow>
```

once you inflated the layout to your convertView variable, you can access all fields view convertview.findViewByID(ID)

Comment: getCount tells the adapter how many item does it has to display, default is 0, getItemId is going to give an ID to each of your views. In getItemId just return the position gives an a param

Comment: I do not understand where you want to replace it

Comment: Please place these methods into your adapter, because these methods are belong to the adapter. Just place them right blow the getView

Comment: @sioesi `getCount()` is essential for your adapter to work.

Comment: You are not overriding anything! that's what the adapter already doing!

Comment: Dear @hasan83, with all do my respect, as an Android developer you may know, this is a bug in Android, if you don't override these methods sometimes it is not going to work, sometimes yes. This is why I wrote, just make sure to override them , when creating custom adapters

Comment: @Karoly Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately that does not work and still receive the same error. You, more experienced, see any errors in my code or my layout?

Comment: @sioesi please update your code, I can recheck it then.

Comment: if I'm right you are updating the first cell in the table right ? I think your code is fine, but the table cell is not getting updated ?

Comment: Sure, I want to update the TextView of the second cell of the table, but I can not reach them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85314/discussion-between-karoly-and-sioesi).

Comment: I never faced such a bug.

Comment: I did, many times. don't ask why, it sometimes comes out on different devices

Comment: Thanks @PPartisan and @Karoly!

Comment: I'd like to add a quick comment. The purpose of using ArrayAdapter is to use lists. Overriding getCount and getItem, although right, makes little since its implentation handles that for you. Use a BaseAdapter instead if you are using different lists. I totally get why @hasan83 was wondering the need to override those methods. This is purely a design choice of course.

Answer (score 1):

`@Override` for `getView` method is messing.

Comment: Override is just for the developer, to make sure are you really overriding the method you wanted to Override. If you don't put there it also okay. from oracle docs: "When overriding a method, you might want to use the Override annotation that instructs the compiler that you intend to override a method in the superclass. If, for some reason, the compiler detects that the method does not exist in one of the superclasses, then it will generate an error. For more information on @Override, see Annotations." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: Im alittle confused since I am just seeing this question. Did he edit and add getView as per this answer?